# Mysql, дописать значения поля значениями из другой таблицы

Tags: mysql, sql

Здравствуйте! Есть БД `Mysql`, в которой есть таблица `user`, в ней есть поле `comment`, в таблице довольно много записей. Нужно взять значения поля `comment` и дописать их соответствующими значениями из другой таблицы `addreses`
где есть поле `user_id` и `adress` (вот эти значения и нужно дописывать в комментарии).

Т.е. в `comment-е` должно быть что-то типа изначальное содержимое + содержимой из таблицы `addreses`.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить эту задачу. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете сделать это следующим запросом:

```
  UPDATE user u
        join addreses a ON u.user_id = a.user_id
    SET
        u.comment = concat(u.comment,' ', a.adress )
```

данный запрос добавит адрес к комментарию в таблице пользователей через пробел

Comment: Добавьте комментарии к Вашему коду

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE user, addresses 
SET user.comment = CONCAT(user.comment,' ',addresses.address)
WHERE user.id = addresses.user_id
```

**ВАЖНО.** Поле `addresses.user_id` обязано быть уникальным. Если это не так - к полю comment будет добавлено одно значение из возможных, причём случайное.

Comment: а можете написать если это поле может повторяться addresses.user_id? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: А это ВЫ должны решить, что в этом случае делать. Добавлять все адреса? некоторые? один? если не все - как выбирать? Главное - составить чёткие и однозначные инструкции. А запрограммировать их - несложно.